# runOnUiThread sometimes does not work - why?

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

I use `OkHttpClient` to fetch data from server and show it in `runOnUiThread` event, but the event does not always work

Basic logic is that I tap on a button, and `OkHttpClient` gets a json from the server, parse it and shows me the json data. Don't know why, sometimes it works fine but in more cases I need to tap for several times for this to work. I test and find out that the json data is always successfully fetched so the problems seems to be that the `runOnUiThread` event is not triggered in a proper way? Sorry I'm new to android

```
private void getDocDetail() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    RequestBody post = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("DocTypeID", Integer.toString(DocTypeID))
                .add("DocID", Integer.toString(DocID))
                .build();

    final Request req = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://127.0.0.1/GetDocData.php"))
                .post(post)
                .build();

    client.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final String s = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(s);
                    AttachCount = jo.optInt("Attach");
                    edtAttach.setText(String.valueOf(AttachCount));
                } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            });
            }
    });
}
```

no error message at all. What I need is that each time I tap the button I can see the `AttachCount` correctly, instead of tapping for 10 times and only 1 time works

when it works fine, the log is very simple like this:

> 2019-07-16 10:56:16.553 13332-13332/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/Timeline:
>
> Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:5633500 intent:Intent {
>   cmp=com.example.lance.platform/.DocsignActivity (has extras) }
>
> 2019-07-16 10:56:16.624 13332-13379/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/ContentCatcher: ViewContentFetcher : ViewContentFetcher
>
> 2019-07-16 10:56:17.093 13332-13337/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=481KB, data=346KB
>
> 2019-07-16 10:56:17.095 13332-13337/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=470KB, data=294KB
>
> But if I tap and nothing happens, the log becomes as below:
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:14.443 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:5151391
>   intent:Intent { cmp=com.example.lance.platform/.DocsignActivity (has
>   extras) }
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:14.554 12870-12896/com.example.lance.platform
>   D/ViewContentFactory: initViewContentFetcherClass
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:14.554 12870-12896/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/ContentCatcher: ViewContentFetcher : ViewContentFetcher
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:14.554 12870-12896/com.example.lance.platform
>   D/ViewContentFactory: createInterceptor took 1ms
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:14.810 12870-12875/com.example.lance.platform
>   I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 7MB to compile void
>   android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:14.845 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/Looper: Slow Frame: doFrame is 318ms late
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.065 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.066 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.066 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:169)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.066 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.066 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1Codec.java:384)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:171)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:153)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.close(Http1Codec.java:400)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.067 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:455)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:106)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:177)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.lance.platform.DocsignActivity$1$1.run(DocsignActivity.java:229)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.069 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.069 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.069 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>
> 2019-07-16 10:48:15.098 12870-12898/com.example.lance.platform
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x6fd8b62000 (ListView)
>   with handle 0x6fd8ac0460

Comment: A good idea is to have debug logs. It makes it easier to find the source of these problems

Comment: yeah post your logs must be a minor problem\

Comment: I think you can just need the `setText` to be just the only content of `runOnUiThread`. Also one trick I do is pass the `View` I need to do something on as parameter of a method. And please learn to format your questions properly, especially the log part.

Comment: somewhat on-topic, `onResponse` is already on the UI-thread, so no need to call `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: Thanks but the problem still occurs. Also I formatted the log as advised

Comment: In that case attach a debugger. Please read on Google how to use it. Example link: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: You are parsing a huge JSON string in the Main Thread.

Comment: *when it works fine, the log is very simple like this:* ?? this log is full of errors

Comment: @Enzokie This is the point! I tried to simplify the json file and the problem is solved! Again thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This code has problem.

```
   final String s = response.body().string();
```

As the log indicates,

```
2019-07-16 10:48:15.068 12870-12870/com.example.lance.platform W/System.err: at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:177)
```

It is very possible network response is not fully received and this will call network socket to get content which will finally become network on UI thread.

So solution is create a member variable mString and set in onResponse:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException 
{
    mString = response.body().string();
```

and in runOnUiThread, use this mString, instead of response.body().string().